# Show or hide sidebar content in Angular, across controllers. Is ui-route right for this?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm currently developing a dashboard, where I have a bunch of modules and controllers in Angular. One of them is taking care of what to show in the sidebar, such as different widgets in different URL's, or states.

I've been using ui-route for the framework (header, footer, main content), but I am not sure if I'm on the right track when it comes to showing or hiding widgets. How can/should this be done?

[Here's a plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/NlpeqlWKxvUstAVbGYlD?p=preview) illustrating the two ways I have - `ui.router`'s state's and `$rootScope.$broadcast` vs `$scope.$on`, giving a list of files I would like to include.

Any thoughts or ideas?

Answer (score 1):

DO NOT use $rootscope for this, that's bad practice all the way around.

Use an abstract state as a parent to your other states. Then you can simply use the parent controller to provide state conditions to the rest of your pages at load time, and a simple ng-if will do the trick after that.

Comment: I've got to ask you here as well - how would that look, it's a bit too abstract for me to grasp.

Comment: @JeffreyColeman I'll contest not using $rootScope as dogma based on misunderstanding. The developers warn not to _abuse_ it (with the common programming notion that global states should be used sparingly), and not to load it up with functions (that's what _services_ are for), but they pretty explicitly say that it's the place for that if you're going to do it. OP is going for a global state, so this a tool for it.

I do agree, though, that doing it through a parent state is better, overall, though they'll have to change their code and learn quite a bit more about Angular to work with them.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the router you use is largely irrelevant. Considering this is global state information, `$rootScope` would probably be the best place to handle whether certain things are shown. I don't think `$broadcast` is even necessary, you can just assign and check properties directly from root scope.

Comment: This is a bit too abstract for me to understand, I am afraid. Could you provide me with some kind of example, maybe in my plunkr?

Answer (score 0):

As Harris Weinstein said, $broadcast looks irrelevant. You can also do something like

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
  $rootScope.currentState = toState.name;
});
```

than you can use ng-if in html to hide and show widgets.

Comment: I am not sure I can follow really. You mean I should have this event listener to listen on the state changes? I am not sure how to trigger these changes, nor where to put this listener. Would you mind to elaborate a bit on this, maybe even in my plunkr?